# Could not delete/rename file

Tags: java, arrays

I want to update my inputFile with the contents of my tempFile.. but it doesn't allow me to delete or rename.. I need help please..

```java
try{
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile, true)));
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = "";

    while(!word.contentEquals("exit")){
    System.out.println("Enter a command: ");
    word = scan.nextLine();
    String entries[] = word.split(" ");



        if(word.startsWith("add")){
            out.write(entries[1] + " " + entries[2]);
            out.write("\r\n");
        } else if (word.startsWith("remove")){
            String currentLine;
            while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
                String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                if(trimmedLine.contains(entries[1])) continue;
                //out.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator")); 
            }
        } else if (word.equals("show")){
            String currentLine;
            while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
                System.out.println(currentLine); 
            }
        }
    }

    }
    finally {
        out.close();
        out.flush();
        reader.close();
        }

        //Delete the original file
    if (!inputFile.delete()) {
      System.out.println("Could not delete file");
      return;
    }

    //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
    if (!tempFile.renameTo(inputFile))
      System.out.println("Could not rename file");

  }
```

Well my whole program should add a Contact or an entry into a file. Then the user could delete or show all the contacts in the text file. Is there another approach to this? Can I overwrite the file instead of using a temporary file? If so, how can i do it?

It always displays "Cannot rename file" or "Cannot delete file" ..

Comment: What problem are you facing? Please attach the issue too!

Comment: Seems probably a permission issue with the folder!

Comment: You could read the file to memory and overwrite the original file instead of using a temporary file, unless you want/need to of course.

Comment: my problem is that it always displays "cannot delete file" or "cannot rename file".. how can i solve this?

Comment: how can i do that? i'm still a student and a beginner ni java.

Comment: Just a guess: The System is still busy reading/writing the files when you request the rename and thus it fails

Comment: Note: Checking `file.exists()` is good practice before attempting to operate on a file.

Comment: Check my answer for how to accomplish your goal without the use of your temporary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the temporary file. As a rule of thumb I only write to files if I'm going to close my program, reopen it and expect said data. I would make `out` a `StringBuilder` and append each line to it instead of the file. Then use the string builder to write back to the file.

```
StringBuilder fileOutput = new StringBuilder();
//your per line logic
//instead of out.write() use fileOutput.append()
System.out.println(String.format("File.canWrite() says %s", inputFile.canWrite());
PrintWriter fileToWrite = new PrintWriter(inputFile);
fileToWrite.println(fileOutput.toString());
fileToWrite.close();
```

If you want to save the previous content of the file, write the previous contents to your `StringBuilder` before you write anything.

Use this if you'd like the previous data saved.

```
String current line = "";
StringBuilder fileOutput = new StringBuilder();
while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    fileOutput.append(currentLine)
}
//the rest of the code above (obviously don't set `fileOutput` twice though)
```

Comment: it works.. but everytime i re-run the program add a new entry.. only the entries that i add are in the file.. and the previous entries are gone.. is there a way to retain the old entries?

Comment: @Gabriel, You want the file to be appended to, instead of overwritten?

Comment: my first attempt was to append.. it worked.. but everytime I remove an entry .. all the entries except the deleted one is appended on the file itself.. resulting to duplicate entries..

Comment: sorry if i'm so confusing.. i can;t express my thoughts clearly.. but please bare with me..

Comment: @Gabriel, It seems you have another question. If you feel I've helped you feel free to accept the answer and or upvote it. If you still are having problems with your code, and it doesn't pertain to this question; feel free to open another question, maybe I'll see it :-)

Comment: thank you so much! it works now.. but how can i print the entries into new lines? they are all printed in a single line..

Comment: @Gabriel, to have each entry on a newline you would append the newline character to your string that you pass to your `StringBuilder`. Like so: Declare `String newLine = System.lineSeparator();` as a field. Then, when appending use `fileOutput.append(whateverYouWantToWrite + newline);`